# jQuery replace image src value if has specific character

Tags: jquery

I have found this code but it's not working.

```
<div class="comments" id="comments">
<div class="avatar-image-container"><img alt="" 
src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zFdxGE77vvD2w5xHy6jkVuElKv- 
U9_9qLkRYK8OnbDeJPtjSZ82UPq5w6hJ-SA=s85" width="100%" height="auto"/>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("#comments.comments .avatar-image-container img[src*='SA=s85']").attr("src","https://rawcdn.githack.com/xysrgithub/blogger/208593eae3ef67c7320246e1a80c6d97656e28dc/img/mementomag/anonymous.png").ssyby("blank");
```

I want to replace src url with the specific character with new src url.

Comment: Can we see the accompanying html? Does your id comments have a class comments? And why do you use * in img[src*='SA=s85'] ? Seeing the html will help us debug this. Also, .ssyby does nothing.

Comment: @Mahatmasamatman I'm sorry, i edited it and add the html. Actually I don't understand it why there is a * in the code, I'm very newbie.

Comment: Star Equal (*=) means: 'contains'

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand your question, you want to replace the source of image if its existing url contains certain character. For achiving this you can use string match() method

```
  var src = $("img").attr("src")
  if (src.match(/SA/g)) {
 $("img").attr("src","https://rawcdn.githack.com/xysrgithub/blogger/208593eae3ef67c7320246e1a80c6d97656e28dc/img/mementomag/anonymous.png")
  }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="SA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure if it's you want but you can try:

```js
const $commentsImg = $('#comments img')

const src = $commentsImg.attr('src')

const hasMatch = /.SA=s85$/.test(src)

if (hasMatch) {
  $commentsImg.attr('src', 'https://rawcdn.githack.com/xysrgithub/blogger/208593eae3ef67c7320246e1a80c6d97656e28dc/img/mementomag/anonymous.png')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments" id="comments">
  <div class="avatar-image-container">
  <img alt="" 
  src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zFdxGE77vvD2w5xHy6jkVuElKv- 
  U9_9qLkRYK8OnbDeJPtjSZ82UPq5w6hJ-SA=s85" width="100%" height="auto"/>
  </div>
</div>
```